# Event and Delegate Issue on one User Control when the User Control is used twice on a page

Tags: c#, events, user-controls, delegates

I have address user control.

I use two address on my page, one for company address and another for mailing address.
So I use my address user control twice on a page.

In this address user control, when the user fills the postal code, I'll pull the street address and building address from DataBase and fills the textbox for the user.

But my issue is whenever the user fills one postal code, both address user control are filled with the same data.

Here is my sample code of address user control

```
public delegate void AddressForServiceHandler(string callType, string refreshType, Dictionary<string, string> keyvalues);
public delegate void MailAddressForServiceHandler(string callType, string  refreshType, Dictionary<string, string> keyvalues);
public event AddressForServiceHandler AddressForService_APICall;
public event MailAddressForServiceHandler MailAddressForService_APICall;


protected void txtPostalCode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            #region delegate func
            Dictionary<string, string> Params = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Params.Add("PostalCode", txtPostalCode.Text.Trim());

            if (AddressForService_APICall != null)
            {
                AddressForService_APICall(txtPostalCode.Text, "PostalCode", Params);
            }
            if (MailAddressForService_APICall != null)
            {
                MailAddressForService_APICall(txtPostalCode.Text, "PostalCode", Params);
            }
            #endregion

    }
```

The **txtPostalCode_TextChanged** event fires both ***AddressForService_APICall*** & **MailAddressForService_APICall** , so both Address user control are filled with same data.

How should I handle this situation ?
I want to populate only one corresponding Address user control.
Thanks in advance.

Kevin

**UPDATE**

Here is my codes that will fill the data. This is coding on **aspx** page.

```
protected void InitializeEvents()
    {
        Address1.AddressForService_APICall += new AddressForServiceHandler(AddressForService);
        Address2.MailAddressForService_APICall += new MailAddressForServiceHandler(MailAddressForService);
    }


protected void AddressForService(string callType, string refreshType, Dictionary<string, string> keyvalues)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ServiceAddress cmProxy = new ServiceAddress())
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> dsPostalCode = new Dictionary<string, string>;
                dsPostalCode = cmProxy.GetAddress(callType, refreshType, keyvalues);// it will return the dictionary filled with the data
                Address1.RefreshAddressForRegistration(dsPostalCode); // here I call address control method to fill the data
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    protected void MailAddressForService(string callType, string refreshType, Dictionary<string, string> keyvalues)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ServiceAddress cmProxy = new ServiceAddress())
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> dsPostalCode = new Dictionary<string, string>;
                dsPostalCode = cmProxy.GetAddress(callType, refreshType, keyvalues);
                Address2.RefreshAddressForRegistration(dsPostalCode);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code which is responsible for the full adress display ?

Comment: I there a particular reason for having two identical (apart for the name) kinds of delegate?

Comment: I tried with just one delegate, the result is the same.
So tried with two delegates , it's still the same.

Comment: Where is txtPostalCode defined? Is it part of your user control?

Comment: Yes, it's a textbox on Address User Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question ad your comments, I understand that txtPostalCode is part of your UserControl, and that txtPostalCode_TextChanged is defined in your UserControl, too, while AddressForService and MailAddressForService are defined in the form containing the 2 UserControls (Address1 and Address2, I suppose).

If this is the case, your error is the fact that your implementation of txtPostalCode_TextChanged is thought as if it already knows that there will be two controls on the form. You should probably simply substitute your events with a single one, like this:

```
public delegate void AddressForServiceHandler(string callType, string refreshType, Dictionary<string, string> keyvalues);

public event AddressForServiceHandler PostalCodeChanged;

protected void txtPostalCode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Dictionary<string, string> Params = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Params.Add("PostalCode", txtPostalCode.Text.Trim());

            if (PostalCodeChanged != null)
            {
                PostalCodeChanged(txtPostalCode.Text, "PostalCode", Params);
            }
    }
```

Then in the Form where you use the UserControls, the code should be:

```
protected void InitializeEvents()
    {
        Address1.PostalCodeChanged += new AddressForServiceHandler(AddressForService);
        Address2.PostalCodeChanged += new AddressForServiceHandler(MailAddressForService);
    }
```

In this way you have 2 UserControls representing an address, Address1 and Address2, and in each of these controls you have a text field (txtPostalCode) which, when changed, executes txtPostalCode_Changed, which fires the PostalCodeChanged for your control.

In the InitializeEvents you subscribe to the PostalCodeChanged event of your user controls with two different methods. This means that when the txtPostalCode of Address1 is changed, PostalCodeChanged is fired only for the Address1 control, and only the methods subscribed to that event will be executed, not the ones attached to the same event in Address2.

If both methods (AddressForService and MailAddressForService) are still executed, there has to be something wrong somewhere else in your code. I would try to debug it, changing txtPostalCode in Address1 with a breakpoint in the method that shouldn't get executed (MailAddressForService). Then I'd take a look at the call stack to understand how you got there, and inspecting Address1's PostalCodeChanged event to see what's subscribed to that event.

Comment: I think it will still fire both events. Thanks for your comment. I'll try and will let you know the result.

Comment: It shouldn't, as long as txtPostalCode_TextChanged is defined inside your UserControl

Comment: It still fire both events.
If I am not wrong, this PostCodeChanged event will fire every subscribed events.

Comment: I just saw that this is aspx. Anyway, I took another look at your code, and it should not behave differently from mine. It's a little bit weird, but it should work anyway, so you are probably right that my solution won't work. Have you tried debugging it? If my version doesn't work, you should find two delegates attached to the event of Address1 and you have to find out where the second one is attached

Comment: I already tried with two delegates and two events, but it just fires every subscribed events.

Comment: Yes, PostalCodeChanged will fire every subscribed event, but there should be only one for Address1 (AddressForService), and another one for Address2 (MailAddressForService). Isn't it so?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Could you explain a bit more ?

Comment: It's OK now. Sorry , I make a mistake when I subscribe.
Thanks for your answer.